# Running bash script with python

Tags: python, bash

I wrote python script to run bash script it runs it with this line:

```
result = subprocess.Popen(['./test.sh %s %s %s' %(input_file, output_file, master_name)], shell = True)

if result != 0:
    print("Sh*t hits the fan at some point")
    return
else:
    print("Moving further")
```

Now I having troubles when bash script fails, python doesn't continue doing what it was doing it just ends. How can I make it so that python script would continue running after bash fails?

Comment: Have you tried `try/except`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about the `communicate`. Besides you `return` when the bash script fails so no wonder the python "just stops".

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(..., stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, error = p.communicate()
if p.returncode != 0: 
   print("Sh*t hits the fan at some point %d %s %s" % (p.returncode, output, error))
print("Movign further")
```

Comment: and what it does?

Comment: Gets the error's stacktrace. But I realized that you just `return` when the `returncode != 0`... No wonder that it "just ends"

Comment: As the documentation already tells you, don´t use bare `Popen` if you can use one of the higher-level functions which take care of exactly these details for you.  In this case, `check_call` or `run(..., check=True)` will raise an exception if the subprocess fails.